# Reaction between Polyvinylpyrrolidone (PVP) and NaOH

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, dispersion-correction

I am using polyvinylpyrrolidone (PVP) as a dispersant in a reaction. The reaction contains concentrated NaOH (pH of the  NaOH solution is 12 to which PVP is added). When I add the PVP, the solution turns yellow. Should this happen?

I was thinking that because of this color change, maybe there is a side reaction that is occurring between PVP and NaOH. I found this [article](http://rloginconsulting.com/joomla/images/SiteFiles/Patents/2combined%20hydroxide%20pvp.pdf) that says PVP reacts with sodium hydroxide to form a gel. But I could not find any other sources that mentioned anything like that article

The temperature of the solution is 25 °C and under agitation to help dissolve the PVP.

Comment: The German version of wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyvinylpyrrolidon) states in section «Eigenschaften» (properties), without literature reference, the following: «Unter alkalischen Bedingungen und erhöhter Temperatur vernetzen die Ketten zu wasserunlöslichen Produkten.».  Google translate translates this into «Under alkaline conditions and at elevated temperatures, the chains crosslink to form water-insoluble products.»

Comment: I check the alkaline condition but the temperature is room temperature.